# Executing 2 commands in 2 different Terminal windows

Tags: python-3, terminal

I want to execute 2 python programs(both run flask servers on different ports) in 2 different terminal windows, from a single bash script.

Python files: `a.py` and `b.py`

Bash Script: `runner.sh`

This is my current bash script, `runner.sh`:

```
a.py
b.py
```

So when I say,
`./runner.sh`
It should execute `a.py` and `b.py` in 2 separate terminal windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can launch a terminal via a command; this should include an option to execute a command inside the terminal as well.

There are various GUI terminal applications available on GNU/Linux.  They are usually paired with the DE (desktop environment).  The default DE on Raspbian ("the DE formerly known as PIXEL", for lack of a better name<sup>1</sup>) is derived from [LXDE](https://lxde.org/), whose terminal app is `lxterminal`.  You can read the documentation for that with `man lxterminal`. The execute option is `-e`, so:

```
lxterminal -e "/usr/bin/python /home/pi/myscript.py"
```

Using quotes here is required if the command contains whitespace. Beware that the terminal will close when `myscript.py` ends, which can make it hard to determine what went wrong if it doesn't work properly.

To get around that what should work (I'm not an LXDE user, but I tested it with another terminal app) is to wrap it in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/python /home/pi/myscript.py
$SHELL
```

This will open a shell (ie., your normal command line) after `myscript.py` exits.  So to use this, `lxterminal -e "/path/to/that/script"`.  The script must be executable (`chmod a+x whatever.sh`).

---

1. Why they decided the DE should not have a name I don't know. It seems the opposite of user friendly, but perhaps that depends which way your head is on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, works well.

Answer (score 2):

Your files `a.py` and `b.py` should have "hash-bang"-lines at the top, to tell the environment how to execute them. They look similar to:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

There is a good chance they are already there, but check to make sure.

Once that is done, your `runner.sh`, placed and executed in the same directory, should look like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
lxterminal -e ./a.py &
lxterminal -e ./b.py &
```

The trailing `&` of the `lxterminal`-lines makes sure that this process is executed in the *background*, and that the script continues to execute.

Comment: works really well. Thanks for the answer.